# default_operator for query_string in ElasticSearch raise error

Tags: elasticsearch

I use this query:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "_source": {
        "exclude": ["Content"]
    },
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "(Content:ربنا)",
            "default_operator": " AND "
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": ["<tag1>"],
        "post_tags": ["</tag1>"],
        "fields": {"*": {}}
    }
}
```

but get error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "No enum constant org.elasticsearch.index.query.Operator. AND "
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "No enum constant org.elasticsearch.index.query.Operator. AND "
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

How can resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the below query. Your `"default_operator"` must be `AND` (without spaces), whereas in your query it is `" AND "` (with spaces). Hence the error.

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "_source": {
        "exclude": ["Content"]
    },
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "(Content:ربنا)",
            "default_operator":"AND"         
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": ["<tag1>"],
        "post_tags": ["</tag1>"],
        "fields": {"*": {}}
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!